# Creating a real 3D website

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

Would it be possible to create a truly 3D website using technologies such as WebGL? By 3D I mean, **using a 3D monitor**.

Firstly does any browser implementation of WebGL provide any type of functionality that allows for 3D such as **Quad Buffering**?

Is there any **other** plausible approach to making a 3D webpage, be-it flash, a browser pluggin etc? (not anaglyph)

Comment: I think now you can make only 3D graphics, but probably, future you can implement 3D monitor support.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430090/has-anyone-created-a-3d-website-that-works-on-a-3d-monitor

Comment: @GabrielSantos thanks, that's what I thought. I've been Googling for an answer, but I can't find anything decisive. That question was asked /answered in 2010.

Comment: Jack, sorry for old question. I can't find another situation like your.

Comment: I just found this interesting video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peTmSXZTt9E

Comment: I have already found this, but, can't find open technology.

Comment: Something like this? http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/07/tilt-visualize-your-web-page-in-3d/

Comment: @FelixKling Nope. Completely different sort of 3D, I want to build a website that will require polarized 3D glasses :)

Answer (score 0):

Side-by-side stereo would work fine for mobile devices, provided you have something like an FOV2Go or Hasbro My3D viewer to look at them:

http://projects.ict.usc.edu/mxr/diy/fov2go/

http://www.hasbro.com/hasbromy3d/en_us/shop/browse/_/N-1rZgt/Ntt-my3d&viewer?Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Items=50&Ntk=All

In this case, you would simply draw your scene twice, at slightly different angles, like the example here:
http://fhtr.blogspot.com/2010/06/webgl-stereo-rendering-demo.html

Comment: Just came across the new stereo renderers in Away3D - if you're not opposed to using Flash w/Stage3D instead of WebGL, it could work... https://gist.github.com/3284386

Comment: Second link is dead

Comment: I'm surprised any of the links are alive - this answer is over 4 years old - ancient in Internet years :)